# Split a string where the word after the @ is an element of the array

Tags: excel, vba

Take this string `"@Steve @Lisa @Matthew Can you take a look at this please?"`

I want to split it into as array that looks like this
`"Steve", "Lisa", "Matthew", "Can you take a look at this please?"`

If I do a `Split` with `"@"` as a delimiter I get the result `"Steve", "Lisa", "Matthew Can you take a look at this please?"`

How do I split the string so all the names get stored as a separate array element?

Comment: Do a second split on the last element, using the `limit` parameter.

Comment: So basically ```Split(StringArray(ubound(StringArray)), " ", 1)``` ?

Comment: Will that create two arrays?

Comment: Yes, using this approach you'd combine them into a third array.

Comment: Yeah that's clever. Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: You could also use `instrrev` to find the last @ character, then `Instr` to find the next space after that, and replace it with an @ using the `Mid` statement. Then split into your array.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
  Dim x As String: x = "@Steve @Lisa @Matthew Can you take a look at this please?"
  Dim arr: arr = Split(Mid(x, 2), " @")
  
  arr(UBound(arr)) = Join(Split(arr(UBound(arr)), , 2), "|")
  arr = Split(Join(arr, "|"), "|")

  Debug.Print Join(arr, ",") ' you can see the joined array in Immediate Window
```

It works for as names prefixed by " @" as they exist. The single condition is the last such a name to be separated by a space by the rest of the last required array string element.

Comment: Imo your code *does* work perfectly for more compound names, too; the only *(unsolvable) exception without further rule indications* would be only the last identified name being prefixed by " @". +:) @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Yes, you are right! If the last word prefixed by " @" is separated by a space to the rest of the (required) last array string, it works well as it is. I will delete the last comment, which looks unappropriated now... Thanks!